# How to count the occurrence of a character and then find its percentage

Tags: r, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

As we know that three sets of codons codes for an amino acids, for example ATG codes just for M (methionine) and ATC, ATA, ATT codes for I (isoleucine)
and percentage of ATG in a DNA sequence would always be 1 for coding M and percentage of ATC in DNA sequence would always be 0.33 for coding I so as ATA and ATT.
I want to make a function which could calculate the counts of the codons in a sequence and then calculate its frequency percentage of forming particular amino acids.

```
codon <- list(ATA = "I", ATC = "I", ATT = "I", ATG = "M", ACA = "T", 
              ACC = "T", ACG = "T", ACT = "T", AAC = "N", AAT = "N", AAA = "K", 
              AAG = "K", AGC = "S", AGT = "S", AGA = "R", AGG = "R", CTA = "L", 
              CTC = "L", CTG = "L", CTT = "L", CCA = "P", CCC = "P", CCG = "P", 
              CCT = "P", CAC = "H", CAT = "H", CAA = "Q", CAG = "Q", CGA = "R", 
              CGC = "R", CGG = "R", CGT = "R", GTA = "V", GTC = "V", GTG = "V", 
              GTT = "V", GCA = "A", GCC = "A", GCG = "A", GCT = "A", GAC = "D", 
              GAT = "D", GAA = "E", GAG = "E", GGA = "G", GGC = "G", GGG = "G", 
              GGT = "G", TCA = "S", TCC = "S", TCG = "S", TCT = "S", TTC = "F", 
              TTT = "F", TTA = "L", TTG = "L", TAC = "Y", TAT = "Y", TAA = "stop", 
              TAG = "stop", TGC = "C", TGT = "C", TGA = "stop", TGG = "W")


( fracs <- 1/table(unlist(codon)) )





      A         C         D         E         F         G         H         I         K         L         M 
0.2500000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.2500000 0.5000000 0.3333333 0.5000000 0.1666667 1.0000000 
        N         P         Q         R         S      stop         T         V         W         Y 
0.5000000 0.2500000 0.5000000 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.3333333 0.2500000 0.2500000 1.0000000 0.5000000

codonfracs <- setNames(lapply(codon, function(x) unname(fracs[x])), names(codon))
str(head(codonfracs))

List of 6
 $ ATA: num 0.333
 $ ATC: num 0.333
 $ ATT: num 0.333
 $ ATG: num 1
 $ ACA: num 0.25
 $ ACC: num 0.25

s <- 'AAGGCCTGCGCAAATATTTCCACTCCTTCCCGGGTGCTCCTGAGTTGAACCCGC
TTAGAGACTCCGAAATCAACGACGACTTCCACCAGTGGGCCCAGTGACCGCCACACTGGA
CCCCATACCACTTCTTTTTGTTATTCTTAAATATGTT
'

strsplit3 <- function(s, k=3) {
  starts <- seq.int(1, nchar(s), by=k)
  stops <- c(starts[-1] - 1, nchar(s))
  mapply(substr, s, starts, stops, USE.NAMES=FALSE)
}
strsplit3(s)

[1] "AAG"  "GCC"  "TGC"  "GCA"  "AAT"  "ATT"  "TCC"  "ACT"  "CCT"  "TCC"  "CGG"  "GTG"  "CTC"  "CTG"  "AGT"  "TGA" 
[17] "ACC"  "CGC"  "\nTT" "AGA"  "GAC"  "TCC"  "GAA"  "ATC"  "AAC"  "GAC"  "GAC"  "TTC"  "CAC"  "CAG"  "TGG"  "GCC" 
[33] "CAG"  "TGA"  "CCG"  "CCA"  "CAC"  "TGG"  "A\nC" "CCC"  "ATA"  "CCA"  "CTT"  "CTT"  "TTT"  "GTT"  "ATT"  "CTT" 
[49] "AAA"  "TAT"  "GTT"  "\n"
```

I have separated my argument into frame of 3. Please guide me in finding the count of each codon in an argument also its percentage of occurrence. It Output for which I am looking for is in the form of table which includes four column Codons, amino acids for which it codes for, count of codons, and percentage of occurrence for forming that amino acids.

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: I am unable to proceed from here, please help me in getting ahead.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer:**  The example in your comment was very helpful.  The code below seems to replicate those calculations.

Since your OP was in base R, I've kept my answer in base R.  However, if you're going to continue to use R for these sorts of analyses, you should consider using the R package `tidyverse` for data manipulation and tabulations.  It's syntax and clarity are significantly better than base R.

```
#
# This should be created as a data.frame but we'll work with the data as given and
# first define Amino_Acid as a vector and then convert to data.frame
# 
  Amino_Acid <- c(ATA = "I", ATC = "I", ATT = "I", ATG = "M", ACA = "T", 
                  ACC = "T", ACG = "T", ACT = "T", AAC = "N", AAT = "N", AAA = "K", 
                  AAG = "K", AGC = "S", AGT = "S", AGA = "R", AGG = "R", CTA = "L", 
                  CTC = "L", CTG = "L", CTT = "L", CCA = "P", CCC = "P", CCG = "P", 
                  CCT = "P", CAC = "H", CAT = "H", CAA = "Q", CAG = "Q", CGA = "R", 
                  CGC = "R", CGG = "R", CGT = "R", GTA = "V", GTC = "V", GTG = "V", 
                  GTT = "V", GCA = "A", GCC = "A", GCG = "A", GCT = "A", GAC = "D", 
                  GAT = "D", GAA = "E", GAG = "E", GGA = "G", GGC = "G", GGG = "G", 
                  GGT = "G", TCA = "S", TCC = "S", TCG = "S", TCT = "S", TTC = "F", 
                  TTT = "F", TTA = "L", TTG = "L", TAC = "Y", TAT = "Y", TAA = "stop", 
                  TAG = "stop", TGC = "C", TGT = "C", TGA = "stop", TGG = "W")

  amino_acid <- data.frame(Amino_Acid=Amino_Acid, Triplet=names(Amino_Acid), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#
#  to avoid end-of-line chararacters in short lines or having a very long line, 
#  use paste to combine several one line strings into one long string
#
  s <- paste0("AAGGCCTGCGCAAATATTTCCACTCCTTCCCGGGTGCTCCTGAGTTGAACCCGCTTAGAGACTCCG",
               "AAATCAACGACGACTTCCACCAGTGGGCCCAGTGACCGCCACACTGGACCCCATACCACTTCTTTT",
                "TGTTATTCTTAAATATGTT")
#
# function to split sequence into codons
#
  strsplit3 <- function(string) {sapply(X=seq(1,nchar(string), 3), 
                                        FUN=function(starts=X, y=string) substr(y, starts, starts+2) ) }
#
# function to return counts in data.frame with given names
#
  table_df <- function(data, column, count_name) {
                   tab <- table(data[, column], dnn = column)
                   as.data.frame.table(tab, responseName = count_name)
  }
#
# identify triplets and amino acid in sequence
#
  codon_seq <- data.frame(Triplet=strsplit3(s))
  num_triplets <- nrow(codon_seq)
  codon_seq <- merge(codon_seq, amino_acid, by = "Triplet")
#
# count triplets and amino acids
#
  codon_seq <- merge(codon_seq, table_df(codon_seq, column = "Amino_Acid", count_name = "AA_cnt"))
  codon_seq <- merge(codon_seq, table_df(codon_seq, column = "Triplet", count_name = "Number") )
#
# remove duplicate rows and calc frequencies and fractions
#
  codon_seq <- unique(codon_seq)
  codon_seq$Freq_1k <- round(1000*codon_seq$Number/num_triplets, 1)
  codon_seq$Fraction <- round(codon_seq$Number/codon_seq$AA_cnt, 2)
#
# Arrange columns in same order as example
#
 codon_seq <- with(codon_seq, data.frame(Triplet,Amino_Acid, Fraction, Freq_1k, Number))
```

This give the result

```
codon_seq
   Triplet Amino_Acid Fraction Freq_1k Number
1      AAA          K     0.50    19.6      1
2      AAG          K     0.50    19.6      1
3      AAT          N     1.00    19.6      1
4      ACC          T     0.30    58.8      3
5      ACG          T     0.20    39.2      2
6      ACT          T     0.50    98.0      5
7      AGT          S     0.33    58.8      3
8      ATA          I     0.50    19.6      1
9      ATT          I     0.50    19.6      1
10     CAC          H     0.50    19.6      1
11     CAT          H     0.50    19.6      1
…
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your help, My apologies. I was not clear about my question. I want to find frequency of each 64 codons according to that codon table. For example if there is a sequence length 2k then, it could calculate total number of each 64 codons repeating in an argument and tell its percentage which together implies for 1. Like if there is 150 GCA 6 GCC 0 GCG and 64  GCT which codes for Alanine(A) it shows its percentage like 0.68, 0.27, 0, 0.29 respectively which together sum for 1. Please tell me if i am still not clear about this problem.

Comment: also i just dont want to calculate frequency from this table but from my argument

Comment: best way to understand my problem is to refer this link [link] (https://www.genscript.com/tools/codon-frequency-table)

Comment: @MayankRajput - I'm glad this worked for you.  You might check the Accept box so that other stackoverflow users with a similar problem could know to consider this approach.

Comment: This worked just fine but what if there is no codon then could you help me in modifying the code to get Fraction 0 for all the 64 codons?